# How can I go about parsing this .txt file into a .Json file?

Tags: json, powershell

I've spent all day trying to figure this out, any help would be great!
This is the text I want to parse into `Json`:

```
============ Get Mouse Position  ===============
    Get Mouse Position
    GetMousePos
    Get the mouse position first
        Command one
        Command two
        Command three
============ Set Mouse Position  ===============
    Set Mouse Position
    SetMousePos
    Set the mouse position after
        Command one
        Command two
        Command three
```

The `Json` output I am aiming for is:

```
{

  "Get Mouse Position": {

    "Trigger": "GetMousePos",

    "Description": "Get the mouse position first",

    "body": [

      "Command one",

      "Command two",

      "Command three"

    ]

  },

  "Set Mouse Position": {

    "Trigger": "SetMousePos",

    "Description": "Set the mouse position after",

    "body": [

      "Command one",

      "Command two",

      "Command three"

    ]

  },

}
```

I've been doing allot of reading and experimenting but I just cant seem to figure it out. the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.2) command gets me mostly there but it does not seem to support arrays for a single key (for command one, two, three section).

I tried to experimenting with `PSCustomObject` and `ConvertTo-Json` like below and it gives me perfect `Json` output but I cant wrap my head around how to properly code my data into the example below for every potential  `===== [Object] ====` section there could be.

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{

    'Get Mouse Position' = [ordered]@{

        Trigger = 'GetMousePos'

        Description = 'Get the mouse position first'

            body = @(

            'Command one'

            'Command two'

            'Command three'

            )

        }

  

        'Set  Mouse Position' = [ordered]@{

            Trigger = 'Set MousePos'

            Description = 'Set  the mouse position last'

                body = @(

                'Command one'

                'Command two'

                'Command three'

                )

            }

}
```

I would really like to know some potential ways I can approach this, that would be so wonderful.
Also, a related question. Does the [ConvertFrom-StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.2) command not support multiple values/arrays for a single key?
Thanks allot

PS: I have taken the liberty to also ask this question in other communities.

Comment: Is it always the same format? Such as the === line denotes the beginning of a record, then within the record the first line is the title, the second is the trigger, the third is the description, and the remaining is the body? If so I've got a solution.

Comment: As for `ConvertFrom-StringData`: it's designed for an array of `<key>=<value>` strings, and doesn't support nesting, which is what you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
# Initialize an ordered hashtable.
$oht = [ordered] @{}

# Split the input file into blocks of lines, not including the header
# (separator) lines.
(Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?m)^===.*\r?\n' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
  # Parse the block of lines into individual lines
  $name, $trigger, $description, $body = $_ -replace '\r?\n\z' -split '\r?\n'
  # Add an entry to the ordered hashtable.
  $oht[$name.Trim()] = [ordered] @{
      Trigger = $trigger.Trim()
      Description = $description.Trim()
      body = $body.Trim()
    }
  }

# Convert the resulting ordered hashtable to JSON
$oht | ConvertTo-Json
```

Note: The above uses a nested `[ordered]` [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) instead of a nested `[pscustomobject]`, as that is sufficient for to-JSON conversion and makes iterative construction easier (while also being more light-weight).
If a nested `[pscustomobject]` instance is desired, replace `[ordered]` inside the `ForEach-Object` script block with `[pscustomobject]` for the nested instance, and then use `[pscustomobject] $oht` to construct the outer instance.

See also:

- `-split`, the [regular-expression-based string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)
- `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string-replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)
- [multi-assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Assignment_Operators#assigning-multiple-variables)

Comment: I just woke up to this.  Amazing, I love how you handeled this, so simple and concise. You even took care to escape Json meta characters such as qoutes and backslashes. Thanks allot, I will refer to your example for every string manipulation I want to do in the future!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @hellen_dorandt89; my pleasure. Note that it is `ConvertTo-Json` that automatically escapes JSON metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since I already did the work I'll go off the assumption that the records are split by the `======` lines, and that within a record the first line denotes the title, the second the trigger, the third the description, and the rest is the body. My suggestion is to read the whole file in as a multi-line string, split on the === lines, and pass to a `ForEach-Object` loop. For the beginning of the loop define an empty object, and for each record passed split it on line breaks into 4 things, and setup your hashtable from that split, and add a property to the object based off that info as well. At the end of the loop output your object that now has a bunch of properties, and pass it to `convertto-json`.

```
(Get-Content MyFile.txt -Raw) -split '(?ms)=.+?[\r\n]+'|
    ForEach-Object -begin {
        $MyObj=New-Object PSObject
    } -process {
        $Split=$_ -split '[\r\n]+',4;
        $ThisVal = [ordered]@{
            Trigger=$Split[1].trim();
            Description=$Split[2].trim();
            Body=$Split[3] -split '[\r\n]+' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'
        };
        Add-Member -InputObject $MyObj -NotePropertyName $Split[0].Trim() -NotePropertyValue $ThisVal
    } -end {
        $MyObj
    }|convertto-json
```

Comment: I too was in the process of composing an answer, so ours overlapped. For robustness, I suggest using `\r?\n` to match a single newline in a platform-agnostic fashion. By contrast, `[\r\n]+` also matches  _multiple_ newlines, as well as `\r` instances in isolation.
(I'm assuming that `\r`-only newlines are not a real-world concern; if they are, use `'\r?\n|\r'`).

Comment: Your assumption was correct. thanks allot for explaining your approach and for your example, it works as expected. I have two great examples to go of on now. so am sorted.

Comment: @mklement0 yep, I saw your answer as the page reloaded when I posted mine. I like how you assigned variables on the split and just captured every thing else in the `$body`, elequently done! You're right, the `[\r\n]+` does eat blank lines, I'll keep that in mind. I try to write my regex specific enough that it won't be an issue, but your solution is nice and I'll have to remember `\r?\n`. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TheMadTechnician, and I appreciate the nice feedback.